# How to implement trigger based on time in mobile?

Tags: android, sql-server, azure, xamarin, sql-agent

I am trying to develope android mobile app and I have bids with limited time and that time decrease if the user click on bid button for example: 
if we have bid with 5 hours and if on click = 1 hour so if five users clicked the bid button then the bid should close.
The problem appear if no one bid on bid so I need to colse it after 5 hours.
So far I have sql server 2016 cloud database with two columns bid and the remaining time and the remaining time decrease by each click. but if noclick I have to check every second using cron job to check the remaining time and close once it reach zero.

I don't think the cron job is the optimal solution I tried to check the trigger time base but didn't find any in sql server.

Could you tell me the best technique to solve the problem may be a new technique to solve it from mobile prospective or sql server view?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just have an ending time, and if it has been reached, the bid is closed, and there's no need to do any updates based on time?

Comment: Yes I have but how to check that it has reached the end time again I will need to check every second which I think not the best

Comment: That's your problem. Why would you need to check every second. Change your solution into something that doesn't require it, so that when the time is reached, the closing will happen without checking

Comment: Do you have any suggestions how to do that ?